# Expand side bar with labels in Gmail

Tags: gmail

How do I show collapsed side bar without having to hover on it? It just started collapsing. How do I fix it? There are no horizontal dots on any of my labels.

Answer (score 2):

Click on the burger menu icon in the upper-left corner to toggle on/off the visibility of the side-bar.

[image]